# Codeception Adding custom assert actions (functional testing)

Tags: yii2, functional-testing, codeception

I'm trying to add new assert methods to Codeception, but without success.
The problem is that I'm not sure where to put my helpers,

Following the doc (http://codeception.com/docs/06-ReusingTestCode), I think I have to create new Helper class but I don't have _support folder. In tests I have only _output folder (excluding my folders).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use command `php codecept generate:helper name` (don't use word Helper in the name, it will be added automatically) to generate the helper class.

Codeception 2.1 names helpers `Helper\Name` - use the full name in your suite configuration files.

If you are interested what's the right path, look at the `paths` section of your codeception.yml file.
http://codeception.com/docs/reference/Configuration